# What does Senjougahara refer in the first novel?

Tags: culture, monogatari-series, symbolism

In the 'Hitagi Crab' story of *Monogatari* series, Senjougahara says the following:

> So you say, Araragi-kun. But I'm afraid I only half trust him. I have been tricked too many times. Five people had said the same thing.
>   They'd all been liars. And... That did not seem like the end of it. Even the hospital -- I only go out of inertia. Honestly, I've pretty
>   much given up. This world may be bizarre, but it has neither Mugen Mamiya or
>   Kudan Kumiko. The best it can manage is Touge Miroku.

Unfortunately, I could not find either description of these characters nor at least where they are from (with exception of Mugen Mamiya) while googling. So, who are they, and why exactly does Senjougahara means by saying that this world does not have them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I haven't read the Japanese edition, and don't have a copy laying around to reference with. I can't say it with 100% certainty. But it seems to be a play of words.

Mugem Mamiya (無限 間宮) *Infinite Momentum*
Kudan Kumiko (件 久美子) *Matter Forever*
Touge Miroku (峠 みろく) *pass (to) Maitreya*

Which would turn the sentence into

> This world may be bizarre, but it has neither Infinite momentum or matter(s) forever. The best it can manage is pass (to) Maitreya.

[Maitreya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maitreya) being "The Buddha of the Future"

> One mention of the prophecy of Maitreya is in the Maitreyavyākaraṇa. It implies that he is a teacher of meditative trance sādhanā and states that gods, men and other beings:
> *Will lose their doubts, and the torrents of their cravings will be cut off: free from all misery they will manage to cross the ocean of becoming; and, as a result of Maitreya's teachings, they will lead a holy life. No longer will they regard anything as their own, they will have no possession, no gold or silver, no home, no relatives! But they will lead the holy life of oneness under Maitreya's guidance. They will have torn the net of the passions, they will manage to enter into trances, and theirs will be an abundance of joy and happiness, for they will lead a holy life under Maitreya's guidance.*

Where the (to) pass Maitreya might refer to the [Three ages of Budhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Ages_of_Buddhism), (to) pass the age of Degenerates